# How to compute normal vector to least square plane in PovRay only

Tags: povray

Is it possible to calculate normal vector to a plane defined by set of points using PovRay only (proper set has more than 3 points)? At the moment I'm using external program that computes via Jacobi eigenvalues of a least square plane.

Still it would be nice not to have to switch for this step to different program but just to use internal procedures of PovRay.

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Jacobi algorithm in povray format. I hope, it would be useful to somebody. As the example a ring is being drawn in the least-square plane defined by 5 points Pts[0..4]. The coordinates of points need to be initialized in the 3rd line. Of course, if the count is other than 5, you need to change variable NoPts in 2nd line.

```
#declare ooo=<0,0,0>;
#declare NoPts=5; 
#declare Pts=array[NoPts]{p1,p2,p3,p4,p5}

// compute centroid              
#declare Centroid=ooo;
#declare i = 0;
#while(i < NoPts )
  #declare Centroid = Centroid+Pts[i];
  #declare i = i + 1;
#end
#declare Centroid = Centroid / NoPts;

// Move points to centroid
#declare nPts=array[NoPts]{ooo,ooo,ooo,ooo,ooo}
#declare i = 0;
#while(i < NoPts )
  #declare nPts[i] = Pts[i] -  Centroid;
  #declare i = i + 1;
#end                   

#declare SM=array[3][3]{ {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0} } // 2nd momentum matrix for coordinates moved to the centroid
#declare EV=array[3][3]{ {1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,1} } // eigen vectors 

#declare i = 0;
#while(i < NoPts )
  #declare SM[0][0] = nPts[i].x  * nPts[i].x  + SM[0][0];
  #declare SM[0][1] = nPts[i].x  * nPts[i].y  + SM[0][1];
  #declare SM[0][2] = nPts[i].x  * nPts[i].z  + SM[0][2];
  #declare SM[1][1] = nPts[i].y  * nPts[i].y  + SM[1][1];
  #declare SM[1][2] = nPts[i].y  * nPts[i].z  + SM[1][2];
  #declare SM[2][2] = nPts[i].z  * nPts[i].z  + SM[2][2];
  #declare i = i + 1;
#end                   
#declare SM[1][0] = SM[0][1];
#declare SM[2][0] = SM[0][2];
#declare SM[2][1] = SM[1][2];

// =============== JACOBI rotation                               

#declare tol = 0.00000001; // tolerance
#declare iterMax = 8;
#declare summ = 0; // control sum


#declare l = 0;            //  ----------- sanity check 
#while(l < 3 )
  #declare m = 0;
  #while(m < 3 )
      #declare summ = summ + abs(SM[l][m]);   
      #declare m = m + 1;     
  #end    
  #declare l = l + 1;     
#end

#if (summ < 0.00005)
  #debug concat("=============== STH WRONG \n")       
#end 

#declare j=0;
#while(j < iterMax)
   #declare ssum = 0;
   #declare amax = 0;
   #declare row=1;
   #while(row < 3)     // ------- loop over rows
     #declare col=0;
     #while(col < row)     // ------- loop over columns
              #declare atmp = abs(SM[row][col]);    
              #if(atmp > amax)
                #declare amax = atmp;
              #end
              #declare ssum = ssum + atmp;
              #if(atmp < amax * 0.1)
                 #declare col = 5; 
              //#end 
              #else
                 #if(abs(ssum / summ) > tol )       //   --- only for "huge" elements ;-)
                    #declare th = atan(2 * SM[row][col] / (SM[col][col] - SM[row][row])) / 2;
                    #declare sin_th = sin(th);
                    #declare cos_th = cos(th); 
                    #declare k=0;
                    #while(k < 3)
                      #declare tmp2 = SM[k][col];                        
                      #declare SM[k][col] =  cos_th * tmp2 + sin_th * SM[k][row];
                      #declare SM[k][row] = -sin_th * tmp2 + cos_th * SM[k][row];
                      #declare tmp2 = EV[k][col];
                      #declare EV[k][col] =  cos_th * tmp2 + sin_th * EV[k][row];
                      #declare EV[k][row] = -sin_th * tmp2 + cos_th * EV[k][row];
                      #declare k = k + 1;
                    #end   
                    #declare SM[col][col] =  cos_th * SM[col][col] + sin_th * SM[row][col];
                    #declare SM[row][row] = -sin_th * SM[col][row] + cos_th * SM[row][row];
                    #declare SM[col][row] = 0;
                    #declare k=0;
                    #while(k < 3)
                      #declare SM[col][k] = SM[k][col];
                      #declare SM[row][k] = SM[k][row];
                      #declare k = k + 1;
                    #end  
                 #end  // end of loop for huge elements
              #end
        #declare col = col + 1; 
     #end // end col
     #declare row = row + 1; 
  #end  //end row
  #declare j = j + 1;  // ' ------- next iteration if not bigger than iterMAX   
#end                                     
// =============== end JACOBI

// find EV with the smallest eigenvalue
#declare EVmin = 10000; 
#declare k=0;
#while (k < 3)
  #if(SM[k][k] < EVmin)
    #declare EVmin = SM[k][k];
    #declare EVindex = k;
  #end
  #declare k=k+1;
#end   


// TEST - draw the ring   

#declare ringRadius=1;
#declare    w = < EV[0][EVindex], EV[1][EVindex], EV[2][EVindex] >;      
object{ 
      torus { ringRadius*.75, Dash_Radius texture { Bond_Texture  } }
      Reorient_Trans(<0, 1, 0>,w)
      translate Centroid
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I assume that the position of the plane is known and that you want to calculate the normal vector. I do not answer the question how this plane is calculated in the first place.

The normal vector to a plane defined by three points (e.g. A, B, C) in (3D) space can be calculated with the cross product of two vectors a=A-C and b=B-C (in the graph below, point A and B would be at the tips of the arrows a and b, respectively. Point C is at the starting point of the two vectors). I also assume that the points are not in a line.

The resulting vector is perpendicular to a and b, therefore it is normal to the given plane.

To get a vector of length 1, you would have to divide it by its length. Now to the question: In POVRay, I assume you have the coordinates in some variables. Then (omitting any #declare statements) you calculate the normal vector (the inices 1,2,3 correspond to the components in x,y,z direction):

n1 = a2*b3 - a3*b2;

n2 = a3*b1 - a1*b3;

n3 = a1*b2 - a2*b1;

The length L of vector n is L=sqrt(n1*n1 + n2*n2 + n3*n3). Now you divide each component by L and you have the normal vector of unit length.

The direction of the normal vector depends on how the three points are arranged on the plane. Counter-clockwise means that the normal vector is directed upwards (or outwards) from the plane, and vice versa. I used this to check whether a surface is visible or not (i.e. its normal vector points towards the point where the camera is located or away from the camera).

Comment: Sorry for not commenting for so long time (to much work lately). Thank you that you took time to write all this stuff. Unfortunately your assumption that I know the plane is wrong. As I have written I want to compute least squares plane first and I have only a set of points (as mentioned more than 3 points; with just 3 of them plain is precisely defined and we do not need any regression method at all). So let me rephrase my question differently - **How to diagonalize [3x3] matrix in povray only?**